# Multiple LIKE Conditions in the same column

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to return a query that when returns all the courses associated with a course code for example 'CSC' will give me a tuple of [('CSCA08H3F',), ('CSCA20H3F',), ('CSCA67H3F',)]...etc. I know I have to use the LIKE clause, but I seem to be doing it wrong as well feel like there is a simpler way of doing this lol...

```
def create_course_table(db, course_file):
'''Courses Table should be ID,Course,Section,Name'''

con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con. cursor()

cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Courses''')

# create the table
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Courses( ID TEXT , Course TEXT , 
Sections TEXT , Name TEXT)''')

# Read CSV File
csv_reader = open(course_file, 'r')
csv_reader.readline()      

# Insert the rows

for line in csv_reader:
    course = line.strip().split(',')
    ID = course[0]
    Course = course[1]
    Section = course[2]
    Name = course[3:]
    for names in Name:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Courses VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', 
                    (ID, Course, Section, names))    

# commit and close the cursor and connection
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()

db = 'exams.db'


def find_dept_courses(db, dept):
'''Return the courses from the given department.  Use  the "LIKE" 
clause in your SQL query for the course name.'''

return run_query(db, ''' SELECT Course FROM Courses WHERE  LIKE Course 'ACT%' 
OR LIKE Course 'AFS%' OR LIKE Course 'ANT%' OR LIKE Course 'AST%' 
OR LIKE Course 'BIO%' 
OR LIKE Course 'CHM%' OR LIKE Course CIT%' OR LIKE Course 'CLA%' 
OR LIKE Course 'CRT%' OR LIKE Course 'CSC%' OR LIKE Course 'CTL%' 
OR LIKE Course 'ECT%' OR LIKE Course 'EES%' OR LIKE Course 'ENG%' 
OR LIKE Course 'EST%' OR LIKE Course 'FRE%' OR LIKE Course 'FST%' 
OR LIKE Course 'GAS%'
OR LIKE Course 'GGR%' OR LIKE Course 'HIS%' OR LIKE Course 'HLT%'
OR LIKE Course 'IDS%' OR LIKE Course 'JOU%' OR LIKE Course 'LGG%'
OR LIKE Course 'LIN%' OR LIKE Course 'MAT%' OR LIKE Course 'MDS%'
OR LIKE Course 'MGA%' OR LIKE Course'MGE%' OR LIKE Course 'MGF%'
OR LIKE Course 'MGH%' OR LIKE Course 'MGI%' OR LIKE Course 'MGM%'
OR LIKE Course 'MGO%' OR LIKE Course 'MGS%' OR LIKE Course 'MGT%'
OR LIKE Course 'NRO%' OR LIKE Course 'PHL%' OR LIKE Course 'PHY%'
OR LIKE Course 'PLI%' OR LIKE Course 'POL%' OR LIKE Course 'PPG%'
OR LIKE Course 'PSC%' OR LIKE Course 'PSY%' OR LIKE Course 'RLG%'
OR LIKE Course 'SOC%' OR LIKE Course 'STA%' OR LIKE Course 'VPA%'
OR LIKE Course 'VPD%' OR LIKE Course 'VPM%' OR LIKE Course 'WST%' AND WHERE Course = ? ''', [dept])
```

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `dept`? How is it related to the course prefix?

Comment: @CL Say I have a list of courses like ('CSCA08H3F', 'ALL', 'HW214'), ('CSCA08H3F', 'ALL', 'HW215') ('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC01', 'AA112'), ('ANTA01H3F', 'LEC01', 'SY110') ('MATB24H3F', 'ALL', 'HW216'), ('MATB24H3F', 'ALL', 'IC120'), ('MATB24H3F', 'ALL', 'IC130')].... If I type MAT for dept, then I will get  ('MATB24H3F',  ('MATB24H3F'), ('MATB24H3F')

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with the proper  [syntax of the LIKE clause.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm)

You've put the column name after "LIKE". Column name comes before "LIKE".

The following query will return the Course column from all rows in Courses where the Course column starts with the given string.

```
SELECT Course FROM Courses WHERE Course LIKE ? || "%";
```

Substitute ? with the desired prefix.

Comment: @ Jemi Silly question but that syntax 'II' means what exactly? Also thank you for helping me minimizing my work.

Comment: @Newbie The || operator concatenates strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since all Course column items are uppercase, then you could use IN instead of LIKE.

Simple test at a prompt that shows that printf used on Course can trim it down to 3 characters and so you can compare to 3 characters of each item to search.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE test (one text);
sqlite> select * from test;
abcd
efgh
ijkl
abcd
efgh
ijkl
abcd
efgh
ijkl
sqlite> select one from test where printf('%.3s',one) in ('abc');
abcd
abcd
abcd
sqlite>
```

Thus find_dept_courses() could use:

```
def find_dept_courses(db, dept):
    '''Return the courses from the given department.  Use the "IN"
    clause in your SQL query for the course name.'''

    return run_query(db, ''' SELECT Course FROM Courses WHERE printf('%.3',Course)
    IN ('ACT','AFS','ANT','AST','BIO','CHM','CIT','CLA','CRT','CSC','CTL',
    'ECT','EES','ENG','EST','FRE','FST','GAS','GGR','HIS','HLT','IDS','JOU',
    'LGG','LIN','MAT','MDS','MGA','MGE','MGF','MGH','MGI','MGM','MGO','MGS',
    'MGT','NRO','PHL','PHY','PLI','POL','PPG','PSC','PSY','RLG','SOC','STA',
    'VPA','VPD','VPM','WST') AND WHERE Course = ? ''', [dept])
```

Edit: If needed sqlite has a upper() and lower() functions to force the case.
[sqlite upper function](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#upper)

Comment: I have reconsidered my current answer. IN() would be a AND... rather than an OR... in theory. Something like a IN ANY() if something like that exists may work. I may look further into it.

Comment: Found no expression or function suitable. Doubt that the current behavior can be changed.